# Regex to find capture groups with last word and the rest of the text

Tags: regex

I am having trouble getting the correct regex to do the following. `17 & Under CP AAA` with `^(?<age>) (?<division>)$` and should give me a capture of `age = 17 & Under CP` and `division = AAA`.  The last word will always be the division.  What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your regex ? What's the language/tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?<age>.*?) (?<division>\S+)$
```

You were actually missing a lot.basically quantifiers.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/16

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?<age>.+?) (?<division>\w+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kI1aW6/1)

`\w+$` will match last word in `division` and before that everything but last space will be in `age` group.